# How do I edit error messages in GCC source

Tags: gcc, internationalization, non-english

I am trying to create a **C Compiler in my native language** which I intend to put up as open source. I want to do this by downloading the **GCC source code** and then manually translating the error messages and warnings into my target language. I am a beginner to GCC. **Any idea where the error messages are located in the source code and how can I edit them?**

Comment: My native language is Marathi, spoken in India. I didnt mean programming language such as Java

Answer (score 6):

GCC is already [localized](http://gcc.gnu.org/translation.html). You don't need to edit any source, just edit (or create, if it doesn't exist) the proper [po file](http://translationproject.org/domain/gcc.html). Getting it into the official distribution seems to require accepting the GNU license (not very surprising); details are on the linked page.

To learn more about gettext, see the [gettext project page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) or the (brief) [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext).

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/help/evaluation.html The GNU coding standards recommend the use of GNU gettext for *all* GNU packages, and many non-GNU packages use gettext as well, so this advice is applicable to translating a wide variety of free programs out there, too.

Comment: My native language is Marathi, spoken in India.
I didnt mean programming language such as Java

Comment: @GccBeginner: Yes, the po files are not in a programming language. Java has nothing to do with this, not sure why you're mentioning it.